# Google Query Language take the last entry of the day

Tags: google-query-language

I have a table of data of the form

```
Date        Time        Product     Count
5/1/2018    8:00 AM     1           17
5/1/2018    5:00 PM     1           4
5/1/2018    5:00 PM     2           6
5/2/2018    5:00 PM     1           7
5/2/2018    5:00 PM     2           2
```

Is it possible for me to set up a query that will choose the latest entry from each day to produce a summary table like this?

```
    5/1/2018    5/2/2018
1   4           7
2   6           2
```

Where the product ID is on the vertical and the count is populating the cells?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Date` is in B1 and ColumnA is populated with:

```
 =ArrayFormula(max(if(B:B=B1,C:C)))<>C1
```

copied down to suit then:

```
=query(A1:E7,"select D,sum(E) where A=FALSE group by D pivot B")
```

with formatting as appropriate.